# A Swipe Views with Tabs consists of 3 fragments

Tags: android, google-maps, android-webview, fragment

In the first fragment is inserted GoogleMap.
In the second fragment - webview that loads a local html page with the text on a white background.
The problem is that when I turn the 1st to the 2nd fragment,  a map from the first fragment is displayed on the second emulator. On а phone, it periodically (during of manipulations with the zoom (magnification, reduction of text on the html page) is displayed as a black square to the appropriate size of the Map with the first fragment. That is periodically flashes a black square.
Tell me what could be the problem?

public class KirovskFragment1 extends Fragment {

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
GoogleMap map;
ImageButton zoomin;
ImageButton zoomout;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kirovskfragment1,container, false);



    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map); 
    map = mapFragment.getMap();
    if (map == null) {
        getActivity().finish();  } 

    if (map !=null)

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(67.609089,33.700819)).title("Кировск"));

    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(61.1, 88.9), 2);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

    zoomin=(ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    zoomout=(ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);


    zoomin.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(67.6090, 33.7008))
            .zoom(8)
            .build();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }});

    zoomout.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(61.1, 88.9))
            .zoom(2)
            .build();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }});




    return rootView;}
```

}

Comment: try to make map object to null in onDistroyView.

Comment: I could not. Help what code you need to add?

Comment: map = null at  onDestroyView.

Comment: public void onDestroyView() 
  {
  map = null;
  } does not work